# Why are member constants available even if there are no instances of a its class?

Tags: c#

1) Why are  member constants available even if there are no instances of a its class?

2) Is the only reason why constant expressions need to be fully evaluated at compile time due to compiler replacing  constant variable with literal value?

3) Since string is also an object, I would think the following would produce an error, but it doesn’t. Why?

```
class A
{
    const string b = “it works”; 
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Constants (declared with `const`) are [implicitly static](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/10/dont-repeat-yourself-consts-are-already-static/) - hence no need for an instance.
2. A `const` value is embedded in the assembly it's declared in, and then every time it's *used*, that value is copied into the calling code as well. Therefore it can't be evaluated at execution time - if you want that behaviour, use `static readonly`.
3. String literals are constant values according to the C# language specification. Basically IL has a metadata representation for strings, allowing them to be specified as constants. String constants also have other interesting properties such as *interning*.

One point of interest: you can declare a `decimal` field as `const` in C#, but that doesn't *really* have CLR support... there's no literal form. The C# compiler fakes it using the `[DecimalConstant]` attribute. That's why you can't use decimal as an attribute argument type.

Comment: As Eric Lippert also noted last Friday: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/10/don-t-repeat-yourself-consts-are-already-static.aspx

Comment: @Johannes: I was just digging up that post :)

Comment: In these comments, Friday means Thursday.

Comment: ... depending on the timezone :-)